# Отправить изображение на сервер из Android-приложения с помощью OkHttp

Tags: java, android, post, okhttp

Подскажите где почитать или поделитесь примером отправки изображения из Android-приложения (Java) на удалённый сервер. Другие данные (текстовые) отправляю с помощью POST-запроса с использованием библиотеки OkHttp, желательно изображение тоже отправлять с помощью неё.

Comment: Обычно такие вопросы легко гуглятся. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622676/image-upload-using-okhttp

Comment: а в чем принципиальное отличие (`ByteString`)